# How to remove page filter from a single visual taken from Embedded Power BI report

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

While trying to embed a single visual from an embedded Power BI report, the page filters applied to the report is also coming along the Visual and I am not able to remove it using removeFilter function mentioned in Power BI playground. I tried like :

- Take the visual from report and tried removing filter to the single visual.
- Remove the filter from report (successful) and get the Single Visual.

In both cases, Visuals are displayed with Filter.

Could anyone please help me out?

Comment: Are you talking about the filters moving with visuals while pinning a visual from Report to a Dashboard?

Comment: Yes, filters are being inherited from report. I am trying to display a single visual on screen taken from a report.

Answer (score 0):

Dashboard are basically for presentation purpose. First you will generate your desired output for a visual in the report using - Slicing, Filtering and drilling down. Once your visual is showing your expected output, you can then PIN your visual to your target dashboard. Remember, once you pinned a visual to a dashboard, you can not change it any more in the dashboard. If you need changes, you need to perform in in the report and then again pin your final output to the dashboard.

Lets go through some comment/explanation from different blogs and tutorials-

> Tiles/visuals pinned to a dashboard are displayed based on the filters applied
> to them via the filter pane OR via slicers OR via cross filtering at
> the time of pinning in report.

> Dashboards do not currently have filters that will allow filtering
> across tiles/visuals.

> A dashboard can contain charts from multiple reports. That’s why a
> sliver doesn't make sense on a dashboard, because the slicer can't
> filter all charts/datasets.

Whatever, I also found some comments as below, but I have not enough knowledge about the approach mentioned.

> If you would like the ability to filter specific tiles on a dashboard,
> pin live report pages

> You can pin a whole report page as a live page, so that any changes
> you make in that report page will be reflected in the live page you
> pinned to your dashboard.

You can do some google about what is power bi **Live Report** is